# Navigation bar in onsen-ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I recently started using Onsen-ui and I love it! I created a sliding navigation bar using there documentation however I would like to alter this navigation bar so that it can only be accessed when the user swipes their finger closer to the left side of the page (not just a full swipe across any part of the page).

Is this possible? I'd appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have something like below in your body of the index.html.

```
<ons-sliding-menu
  above-page="home.html"
  behind-page="menu.html"
  max-slide-distance="85%"
  side="left"
  var="app.slidingMenu">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

Change it so that it looks like this:

```
<ons-sliding-menu
  above-page="home.html"
  behind-page="menu.html"
  swipe-target-width="20px"
  max-slide-distance="85%"
  side="left"
  var="app.slidingMenu">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

i.e. add the following line:

```
swipe-target-width="20px"
```

For more reading: http://onsenui.io/guide/components.html#ons-sliding-menu

Hope it helps & Good luck with Onsen!

Vladyslav